# How can I translate infix to mathml using the python interface to libsbml?

Tags: modelling, systems-biology, sbml

Assume I have an infix expression such as k1*s1, how do I use libsbml to translate this expression to mathml using the python interface?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Can you include examples if what you have already tried?

Comment: See answer below. It works, I tried it.

Answer (score 4):

It’s quite straightforward to convert infix to mathml using libsbml. Make sure you have libsbml installed in python by typing

```py
pip install python-libsbml
```

at the windows/Mac/Linux command line or

```py
!pip install python-libsbml
```

if you are running a Jupyter notebook. Some tools such as [Tellurium](http://tellurium.analogmachine.org/) already have libsbml preinstalled.

At the python command line type

```py
import libsbml
```

to import the package. To enter the infix expression type the following:

```py
p = libsbml.parseFormula ('k1*s1')
```

To generate the mathml type

```py
print (libsbml.writeMathMLToString (p))
```

Comment: One should use the newer `libsbml.parseL3Formula` which provides the full set of SBML Level 3 formula parsing.  I recommend using the extended `libsbml.parseL3FormulaWithModel(formula, model)` which uses a model instance to resolve the actual symbols in the formula. Thereby it is clear if all the symbols exist in the model. If the functions return `None` make sure to check the `getLastParseL3Error` to find out what went wrong.